# Unable to create a new playlist in iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone

I am unable to create a new playlist for my iPhone4. When I right click the iPhone in iTunes the option 'Create New Playlist' is greyed out. I'm using the latest version of iPhone OS & iTunes.

I can create new playlists in iTunes itself just not on the iPhone.

Any ideas on what this issue is ?

Comment: It's a feature (honestly)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the same for me, but you can create your playlist on iTunes and then sync it to your iPhone.

Alternatively you can create the playlist directly on your iPhone. Just open `Music`, go to the tab `Playlists` and select `Add Playlist...`.

Comment: can you elaborate on "create your playlist on iTunes and then sync it to your iPhone" I can create the playlist on iTunes but how do I sync it to my phone ?

Comment: Select your iPhone in iTunes, go to the tab `Music`, check the flag `Sync Music`, and the check `Entire music library` or select the desired playlists.